# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am facing an issue while assign value to `DateTime stdt`
please find below my code logic

**startdate**="06/20/2016 12:30" //format (MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm)

> DateTime stdt = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate);

also, I had tried with below code but didn't work.

> DateTime stdt = DateTime.ParseExact(startdate, "dd/MM/yyyy",
>   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: Try `DateTime.ParseExact(startdate, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` . With `ParseExact` you have to give the exact format

Comment: I had tried with as your solution but I am getting this error 'The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.'

Comment: @AKS : are you sure the string you parse is exactly the one on your example, with no hidden characters or other problems ? The Pikoh's answer seems ok for me.

Comment: @aks note 'MM' before ´dd´

Comment: sorry @Pikoh your solution is working I just forgot to change "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According your date, you should use :

```
DateTime stdt = DateTime.ParseExact(startdate, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

to match each part of your date.

Please see here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for method usage

And https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx for date patterns

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
DateTime stdt = DateTime.ParseExact(startdate, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

you have to put the formatting of the string that you pass to the method.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass the format, you can use the culture:

```
 var date = DateTime.Parse("06/20/2016 12:30", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: I think this will fail : "MM/dd" is not the typical usage for french dates, day is before month in french, so this will fail. If dateformat is always the same, it seems better to me to use explicit pattern.

Comment: Yes that's true I only wanted to give an idea of how to proceed (-; Should work with "new CultureInfo("en-US")"